# how to set database string value to null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

There are some value contain in my database `branch column` for example "B01",

 I am trying to set my branch column back to null value

 I had tried

1. string.Empty
2. String.Empty
3. ""
4. null
5. DBNull.value

Noted* all the method able to set my value back to "" but not my expected result, my expected result is my column back to "NULL" but not ""

```
    if (ddlBranches.SelectedIndex > 0 && ddlLocation.SelectedItem.Text.ToUpper() == "BRANCH")
    {
        drUpdProb["Branch"] = ddlBranches.SelectedValue.ToString();
        drUpdProb["BranchAbbr"] = ddlBranches.SelectedItem.Text;
    }
    else
    {
        drUpdProb["Branch"] = DBNull.value;
        drUpdProb["BranchAbbr"] = DBNull.value;
    }
```

Comment: You are looking for `DBNull.Value`

Comment: oops, i tried that too, not working

Comment: what is your database? what is 'drUpdProb'? can you show the update code? is it working for not null value?

Comment: or why not use `string.Empty` instead of setting it to `null value`?

Comment: put your query also and what database you are using

Comment: Is this field nullable? I'm not sure about what you're using for DBMS but the scheme for the table might not allow your field to be set to null. What error are you getting when you try to set the field to DBNull.Value?

Comment: DBNull.Values should work.. perhaps you are doing doing something incorrectly with the way that you are updating and or trying to set the value in the database.. also can you provide more code..? i.e the method where this code you have above looks like.. you need to also provide a DB Schema show the field definition as how that table was created and it's allowable data types

Comment: oops, sorry DJ, previously my DB do not accept null value, that the main problem

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following create a parameter to assign values

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Branch", drUpdProb["Branch"] ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BranchAbbr", drUpdProb["BranchAbbr"] ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
```

Comment: -1: Good try, but the amount of detail totally obscures the answer.